# c# run form from other project in same solution

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I have C# solution with windows forms in visual studio 2015. In solution there are two projects: project A, project B.

If I run project B, login dialog shows. if login passes, main form is opened.

I want the same behavior if I click on button in project A. But it shows only dialog, but clicked login, main form **doesn't open**.

This is original working code from project B:

```
 static void Main() {
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

     LoginForm pf;
     Application.Run(pf = new LoginForm ());

     if (pf.Zakaznik != null)
         Application.Run(new MainForm(pf.Zakaznik));
 }
```

And this is code from project A:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    UC001.View.LoginForm pf = new UC001.View.LoginForm ();
    pf.Show();
    if (pf.Zakaznik != null) {
        UC001.MainForm a = new UC001.MainForm(pf.Zakaznik);
        a.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling [`Show()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show.aspx) you should call [`ShowDialog()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx). The latter method will block your code till the user closed the window. By calling the first method, your code immediately continues without waiting for the user closing the dialog, leading to be `pf.Zakaznik` always being `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the Form by referencing it using

```
var f = new ProjectB.Form1.cs(); 
f.Show();
```

Your Other form isn't showing (your main one) because it's already open. Once you open a new one, you need to do `this.Close();`. When you show another form, it actually only hides the other one (or leaves it alone).